# Sampling in the wrong direction R

Tags: r, random, sampling, resampling

## Background

I have two variables called `x` and `y` (*please see R code below the picture*). When I `plot(x, y)`, I obtain the **top-row plot (see below)**. **y values** are stacked over the top of **each x value**. I then try **to sample from these `y` values** and make a second plot below the mother plot.

## Question

I am wondering WHY when I use the `predit.range` (**see R code below**) to be `10:0` (the problem doesn't happen when I use `0:10`) **my sampling procedures goes completely in the wrong direction?** (***please compare the top-row plot to the bottom-row plot***)

[image]

```
############# Input Values ################
                      each.sub.pop.n = 150; 
                      sub.pop.means = 20:10; 
                      predict.range = 10:0; 
                      sub.pop.sd = .75;
                      n.sample = 2;
#############################################
par( mar = c(2, 4.1, 2.1, 2.1) )

m = matrix( c(1, 2), nrow = 2, ncol = 1 ); layout(m)

Vec.rnorm <- Vectorize(function(n, mean, sd) rnorm(n, mean, sd), 'mean')

y <- c( Vec.rnorm(each.sub.pop.n, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd) )

x <- rep(predict.range, each = each.sub.pop.n)

plot(x, y)

## Unsuccessful Sampling ## The problem must be lying in here:

sampled <- lapply(split(y, x), function(z) sample(z, n.sample, replace = TRUE))
sampled <- data.frame(y = unlist(sampled), 
                 x = rep(predict.range, each = n.sample))
plot(sampled$x, sampled$y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sufficient to illustrate why.

```
x <- 10:0; y <- 10:0
```

Did you notice how

```
split(y, x)
```

sorts the list? To get your desired ordering, control factor levels:

```
split(y, factor(x, levels = unique(x))
```

In your context, you can use efficiently without `unique`:

```
split(y, factor(x, levels = predict.range))
```

Comment: Zheyuan, my sampling question has to do with THIS question that I asked yesterday. Can I here  use:   `sampled <- lapply(split(y, x), function(z) sample(z, n.sample, prob = dnorm(x, sub.pop.means, sub.pop.sd), replace = TRUE))`

Comment: Let's talk here! see my above comment returns error!

Comment: There is more interesting question aside from this sampling. Apparently, sample regression line is never so off from the population regression line!